# why did the wallet connection stopped working and any fix?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, web3js, ethers.js

so my dapp been working for over 6 months now and today i woke up tested and it stoppedthe wallet still connect but all the functions stopped working help plz

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
function connectWallet() {
    ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" }).then(async (accounts) => {
        address = accounts[0];
        web3.eth.setProvider(Web3.givenProvider);
        let _wallet = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(address);
        $("#connectWallet").hide();
        $("#disconnectWallet").text(_wallet.slice(0, 6) + "..." + _wallet.slice(_wallet.length-4, _wallet.length));
        $("#disconnectWallet").show();
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
}




function disconnectWallet() {
    address = "";
    $("#disconnectWallet").hide();
    $("#disconnectWallet").text("0x000...0000");
    $("#connectWallet").show();
    $("#walletBalance").text("0 USDT");
}



window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function (accounts) {
    if(accounts.length > 0) {
        connectWallet();
    } else {
        disconnectWallet();
    }
})



$("#connectWallet").click(function() {
    connectWallet();
    $(".onConnect").removeClass("disabled");
});



$("#disconnectWallet").click(function() {
    disconnectWallet();
    $(".onConnect").addClass("disabled");
    $("#stats_total_staked").text("0 USDT";
});



$("#disconnectWallet").hover(function() {
    $(this).text("Disconnect");
}, function() {
    let _wallet = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(address);
    $(this).text(_wallet.slice(0, 6) + "..." + _wallet.slice(_wallet.length-4, _wallet.length));
});
```